# Where to find universal asus sound driver for xp?

Tags: windows, audio, motherboard

I have asus a7S333 motherboard and can't hear sound, so is there any where to find universal asus sound driver or driver for motherboard that use xp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search led me here: [ASUS A7S333 Driver Download page](http://www.driverstock.com/ASUS-A7S333-driver-download/6-9-10236/index.html).

Try installing the one closest to the top of the page (V5.12.01.0635) and see if it works.  Let us know the results!

Edit:
Try [ASUS download page](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=A7S333&p=1&s=10).  Select your OS (WinXP) from the dropdown.  Click on Audio.  Try the link that says "Global".

The read-me file in there is pretty unhelpful, so after unzipping, try opening Device Manager (Windows Key + Pause Break), choosing your audio/sound card, choosing to update the drivers, and try pointing the installer to the unzipped folder.
As before, let us know the results!